# Display the correct value in the textbox

Tags: jquery, textbox

I have something know as a Number of answers Textbox (#numberAnswerTxt). Now at the moment I am using this code:

```
$('input#numberAnswerTxt').val('');
```

Now what this does is that everytime I open up the (open grid) link and choose an option, the Number of Answers Textbox goes back to being empty.

Now what I want is this line of code to change so that everytime a user changes options from a grid, instead of the textbox going blank, I want the textbox to display the figure of the number of answer buttons which have been selected.

The answer buttons are buttons "A" to whatever letter and they are selected if the button goes green.

So follow these steps and see if you can get this outcome:

1. Open the grid and select option "3". Buttons A B and C would apear.
2. Type in number "2" in the number of answers textbox and select buttons A and C would turn green and the number of Answers textbox would display the number 3.
3. Now change the option from the grid from "3" to "7". Now all the answers except for "B" are seelcted. Now in the textbox it should display "6" for number of Answers but at moment is displays a blank textbox.

So how can it be coded so that in the number of answers textbox if the grid option changes, it displays in the textbox the number of answers which are selected?

Thanks

`$('input#numberAnswerTxt').val('');` is in the   `$(".gridBtns").click(function()`  .

The full code is in Jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C7vcQ/2/)

Comment: (3) above is not happening in your fiddle. When I change from 3 to 7, only A & C are highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

`$('input#numberAnswerTxt').val($('input.answerBtnsOn').size());`

Comment: sorry wrong fiddle, I editted fiddle, thanks I have to go now so if you need to comment to me then I will be back in 1 hour thanks